# Работает только один раскрывающийся блок из всех

Tags: jquery, html, php, css, mysql

Как сделать, чтобы работали все?

Создал шаблон блока с `SlideToggle`. Вызываю из БД все записи(блоки), но при нажатии работает только один из них. Кликаю по второму, но он не работает. Как это исправить?

[Вот ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/G2Y46/)

Comment: код выкладывайте

Comment: пройдитесь по ссылке "вот ссылка:"

Comment: поинтересуйтесь, чем отличается id от class

Comment: Я знаю чем отличается. Но дело в том, что когда ставлю класс, то при нажатии на один блок сворачиваются и все остальные вместе. Мне это не нужно

Comment: > Я знаю чем отличается.

Похоже, что не просто не знаете, а даже и малейшего понятия не имеете. Вот [ваш пример с классами][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/G2Y46/1/

Comment: спасибо. Последнее, как сделать, чтобы верхний блок при открытии выдвинул нижние блоки?

Comment: @navi1893 да блин, сделайте блокам разные id. В у каждого элемента в документе должен быть уникальный id!

Answer (score 1):

```
   $('div#topic_title').click(function() {
        $(this).next("#topic_body").slideToggle();
});
```

http://anton.shevchuk.name/javascript/jquery-for-beginners-selectors/
О выборке

Answer (score 1):

замените id на классы, и замените

```
$('#topic_title').click(function() {
        $('#topic_body').slideToggle();
});
```

на

```
$('.topic_title').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.topics').find('.topic_body').slideToggle();
});
```

где: `$(this)` - элемент .topic_title, конкретно тот, по которому кликнули.
ищем ближайшего родителя .topics -  `closest('.topics')`
далее, у .topics ищем дочерний элемент .topic_body - `find('.topic_body')`
и сворачиваем/разворачиваем его :)